# Panel for a slimline DVD drive

Tags: hardware-rec, case

I am looking at nixing my DVD drive in my HTPC/Nettop box, and replacing it with a new HD. Where might I find a cover that would fill the gap where the DVD drive used to be on the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [this link](http://hddcaddy.eu/2011/12/15/which-hddcaddy-fits-in-my-laptop/) there are videos and other information about the subject.

Basically it breaks down to four different caddy types:

- SATA 12.7mm
- PATA 12.7mm
- SATA 9.5mm
- PATA 9.5mm

Answer (score 3):

The best place would be from the HTPC case manufacturer.  They will have the bay covers that will match the color and finish for your model, as well as have the proper snapping connectors.

Answer (score 1):

Applying some common sense to the problem, leaves me with following options:

1. Go to a local PC (repairs) shop and ask to get or buy one such item in your preferred color
2. Saw it out of wood and apply your favorite color
3. Buy online

Comment: I'm not sure how to find these online. Is there a formal name for them?

Comment: Good question. I would start the search with "bay panel replacement HTPC"